# abstract class with multiple constructors in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a `Command` `class` that I want to parse to string / from string to send it as a `UDP` message. The base class look as simple as:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    public Command() {}
    public abstract override string ToString();
    public abstract void FromString(string str);
}
```

From here I derive `classes` like

```
public class NetCommand : Command
{
   public string details;

   public NetCommand() {};
   public override string ToString() {return details;}
   public override void FromString(string str) {details = str; }
}
```

Or a bit more complex `MovementCommand : Command` that containes `x`,`y`,`z` `doubles` that get parsed and so on.

How can I add a constructor in the base `class` that takes `string` and uses the `FromString` method?
Is going to have the same exact code for all derived classes and it is going to look like:

```
public Command(string str)
{  
    this.FromString(str);
}
```

and each `class` will fill its own members from the string using its own `FromString` method.

But I'm lost with the syntax, any help?

Comment: `public NetCommand(string str) : base (str) {}` ?

Comment: this is what  was looking for, although I though that it was possible to include this constructor with NO code in the derived class, just assuring that any derived class would have this constructor. If you add this as solution I will accept it.

Comment: sure, no problem. added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is exactly what you are asking for, including changes to abstract class:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    public Command() { }
    public Command(string str)
    {
        FromString(str);
    }
    public abstract override string ToString();
    public abstract void FromString(string str);
}
public class NetCommand : Command
{
    public string details;
    public NetCommand() {}
    public NetCommand(string str) : base(str) { }
    public override string ToString() { return details; }
    public override void FromString(string str) { details = str; }
}
```

Comment: what happens if someone inherits from Command, does not include the line `public `MyCommand(string str) : base(str) { }` and you try to invoke it ? looks like a weak point here :(

Comment: You required from the abstract class to implement Command(string str), if you are not going to use it in a class inheriting Command, then it is unnecessary as abstract classes can not be created directly. No, you can not force class inheriting from an abstract class to implement all its constructors, language does not require that.

Comment: You can not directly invoke a constructor that does not exist. Different story with reflection, but then it would fail. You simply want something to be done or not:).

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand you is that you want to have a *base class constructor* that creates a *sub class object*. You can't do that.

What you can do is create a static factory method on the base class that creates the concrete objects based on the given string, e.g.

```
public abstract class Command
{
    public Command() {}
    public abstract override string ToString();
    public abstract void FromString(string str);

    public static Command FromString(string str){
        Command command;
        if(/*string indicates it is a NetCommand*/){
            command = new NetCommand();
            command.FromString(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, probably better: `command = new NetCommand(str)`, where `NetCommand(string str)` is a private / protected constructor.

Comment: @CompuChip yea, that would probably be the better design

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for since from the look of string you cannot guess the kind of command (they are all just a bunch of numbers)

Comment: @javirs How are you planning on deserializing it if you have no way of knowing the exact type?

Comment: Guys, there is one design flaw. The static FromString is returning Command, but it is actually NetCommand. But the author says, that there will be more than one class inheriting from the abstract class Command. It would mean that either there would have to be multiple versions of static FromString for each implementation or there would have to be anther mechanism, like public static TRslt FromString<TRslt>(string str) where TRslt : Command

Comment: @ipavlu Where exactly do you see a design flaw? That the return type is `Command`?

Comment: You are forcing design decisions on implementation of the protocol, without necessary information we were not provided. And the result is a reference to an abstract class, not the result class. We simply do not have necessary information if that is the way it should behave. ANd result would have to be later tested whether it is one of N implementations of Command.  Think about case, where you know in the protocol exact placing of the sequence of commands and each class implementing the Command, then header info is not necessary, or they can have all same data etc.

Comment: @ipavlu you are right, we dont really know if this is the case. Luckily this is not the only answer and OP can choose the one that fits best for his solution. However, this is the case you normally have when serializing something and sending it over a network.

Answer (score 0):

Have a backing field that stores the value passed through the constructor and then two virtual methods that set and return that value. Note that in the below implementation the `NetCommand` can only be instantiated with non-parameterless constructor.

```
public abstract class Command
    {
        private string _details;

        protected Command()
        {
        }

        protected Command(string details)
        {
            _details = details;
        }

        public new virtual string ToString()
        {
            return _details;
        }

        public virtual void FromString(string details)
        {
            _details = details;
        }
    }

    public class NetCommand : Command
    {
        public NetCommand(string str) : base(str)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this implementation (put as many code into base class as possible in order to ease further classes creation)

```
public abstract class Command {
  protected Command(): this(null) {
  }

  protected Command(String details) {
    Details = details;
  }

  // I'd rather convert it into property
  public String Details {
    get;
    set; // may be "private set" will be better here
  }  

  public override string ToString() {
    return Details;
  }

  // TODO: think on delete or redesign this method:
  // Redundant: Details provide all the functional required
  // Bad name: "FromString" usually means create/return
  // instance by given details
  //  public static Command FromString(string details)  
  public virtual void FromString(String details) {
    Details = details;
  }
}

...

public class NetCommand: Command {
  public NetCommand(string details) : base(details) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Domysee's answer, using a generic factory method you could do the following:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    protected Command() {}
    public abstract override string ToString();
    protected abstract void FromString(string str);

    public static T FromString<T>(string str) where T: Command, new()
    {
         var command = new T();
         command.FromString(str);
         return command;
    }
}
```

Now, as long as the derived Command has a default constructor, you can create instances of it using Command.FromString like this:

`var command = Command.FromString<NetCommand>("command string");`